# Generating result by matching two string but eliminating verbs and few other specific words like "the, they, there them etc"?

Tags: c#, string, algorithm, string-matching

Consider there are two strings to be matched to find the similar words. on the basis of match of specific words, the o/p should be "0 for no match" "1 for 1-word match  ","two for the 2-word match" & "3 for 3 or more word matches" The condition of the problem is that we can't use the few specific words such as is, am, are, they, the etc and match should not be considered for the result.

Comment: [idownvotedbecau.se/unclearquestion](http://idownvotedbecau.se/unclearquestion) - so what is your exact question? What is the problem? What are your attemps in solving?

Answer (score 0):

Since the question is not pretty clear ,i am going off what i think you might mean.

You can create a hash table with all the words of the first and the second string . Then you can check to see their sizes to get your output. This way you are not checking for specific words